# Angular: Declaring target domain/IP globally

Tags: angular

I am working on an application and sending an HTTP request to the backend server. Since, there are a lot of components therefore, each time I want to deploy the application I have to change the `localhost` to the target domain/IP.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData => {
     console.log(responseData);
})
```

Before building it for production mode I have to do something like this for each HTTP request:

```
this.http.post('http://IP.OF.THE.SERVER:3000/api/login', form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData => {
     console.log(responseData);
})
```

or, something like this for each separate component

```
this.http.post(`http://${this.ipServer}:3000/api/login`, form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData => {
     console.log(responseData);
})
```

My question is that is there any way I can declare the domain/IP globally somewhere in the project like in angular.json file so, that it can be used by every angular component?

I don't want to use service for this purpose. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use **src/environments/environment.ts** & **src/environments/environment.prod.ts**. In angular.json u have settings which replace env.ts with env.prod.ts

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
],
```

so just put in each file same setting with diff values

Answer (score 0):

Use **src/environments/environment.ts** for this purpose

Define your configs in environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serverIp: 'localhost'
};
```

Import environment.ts wherever you want and use it like below

```
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
    
this.http.post(`http://${environment.serverIp}:3000/api/login`, form.value, {responseType: "text"})
      .subscribe(responseData => {
         console.log(responseData);
    })
```